# HTML / JS problema de uso onclick

Tags: javascript, html

¡Hola comunidad!
Estoy tratando de crear una variable que me tome valor de un cuadro de texto al presionar un botón e imprimir variable en pantalla, pero me da un error. Estoy comenzando a estudiar el javascript y estoy algo perdido.

Gracias.

**HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Juego de Trivia</h1>
    <text>Ingresa tu nombre:</text>
    
        <form>
         <input type="text" id="texto" />
         <input type="submit" value=">>" onclick="guardado">
        </form>
         <script src="script.js"></script>
        
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var valor = document.getElementById("texto").value;
document.write(valor);**
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el error?

Comment: No te preocupes, yo estoy aprendiendo pero te voy a ayudar

Comment: A toda persona que llegue aquí: TODOS son bienvenidos a hacer preguntas, ESPECIALMENTE para aprender. Sí existen manera eficientes de hacer las preguntas, sean de principiante o avanzado. Estas maneras tambien se aprenden. Aprendizaje siempre hay no importa el nivel.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Aqui tambien se viene a aprender.. todos aprendemos todo el tiempo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui tenes lo que conseguí hacer, espero que te sirva el resultado.

```js
document.body.innerHTML = `<h1>Juego de Trivia</h1>
    <text>Ingresa tu nombre:</text>
    
        <form>
         <input type="text" id="texto">
         <input type="button" value=">>" id="boton">
        </form>`;
//con las comillas `` puedes meter el contenido entero de un documento para imprimirlo en el propio dom
//como ves, lo primero que hago es un document.body.innerHTML = `contenido`
//esto es totalmente equivalente a si lo insertas dentro del html. Es literalmente lo mismo, solo que yo
//lo puse de forma dinamica. Esto te ayudara en el futuro, aśi que no lo pierdas, se les llama plantillas literales
//o template strings en js
//Te habras fijadoe n que cambie el tipo del input submit, ya que al estar detro del formulario, mandabas el formulario a traves de la web
//aunque hubieras tenido TODO bien, no hubieras visto nada por eso, asi que lo primero a cambiar es eso

        let btn = document.getElementById('boton');//le puse de id boton, y cree un addEventListener a los clicks
        btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
            guardado();//donde te manda directamente a la funcion guardado, importante añadir los parentesis ()
            //esto funciona igual que el evento onclick del boton que tu creaste
        });

function guardado(){//establecemos la funcion guardado()
    let inp = document.getElementById('texto');//obtenemos SOLO el input
    console.log(inp.value);//e imprimimos en consola el VALOR del input

    //si quieres hacer un document.write(inp.value) tambien serviria
}
```

Pd: en StackOverflow también se viene a aprender, solo que hay que formular bien las preguntas. ;D

Comment: Buena respuesta. Puedes simplificar omitiendo la función anónima para dejar solo el nombre de la función a ejecutar cuando se reciba el clic: `btn.addEventListener('click', guardado);`

Comment: True, pura costumbre de hacerlo siempre así